# Kerberos SPNEGO Authentication with multiple SPN and AES256 on Samba 4.11

Tags: java, kerberos, samba, spnego

I have a HTTP service written in Kotlin and using Tomcat that listens in multiple domains and those need to be authenticated via Kerberos. On Samba 4.9 we had a user with multiple SPNs with AES256 encryption enabled. A keytab was generated for that user containing all SPNs.

After upgrading to Samba 4.11, multiple SPNs in a single user stoped to work. The error `Client 'HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM' not found in Kerberos database while getting initial credentials` was thrown. We fixed that by creating multiple users, one for each SPN and setting the UPN to the value of the single SPN. After that we generated keytabs for each user and then we merged it.

The problem is that when I receive a ticket with `aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96`, `java.security.GeneralSecurityException: Checksum failed` is thrown and just works in one domain, the one I use as principal. `arcfour-hmac-md5` works just fine on all domains, but I need to support AES encryption.

I've tested this scenario on our old Samba 4.9 and the same happens. If we have multiple users with a single SPN each and a keytab with all of them, `Checksum failed` is also thrown.

So either I manage to have a single user with multiple SPNs working on Samba 4.11 or I have to get rid of the `Checksum failed` when using AES encryption.

#### java -version

```
openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.6+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.6+10, mixed mode)
```

#### JAVA_OPTS

```
-Dsun.security.krb5.disableReferrals=true
-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true
-Dsun.security.spnego.debug=true
```

#### .java.login.config

```
example {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
            keyTab="/root/HTTP.keytab"
            principal="HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM"
            debug=true
            storeKey=true
            useKeyTab=true;
};
```

#### HTTP.keytab

```
Vno  Type                     Principal                          
  2  aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96  HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
  2  aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96  HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
  2  arcfour-hmac-md5         HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
  2  des-cbc-md5-deprecated   HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
  2  des-cbc-crc-deprecated   HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
  2  aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96  HTTP/b.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
  2  aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96  HTTP/b.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
  2  arcfour-hmac-md5         HTTP/b.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
  2  des-cbc-md5-deprecated   HTTP/b.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
  2  des-cbc-crc-deprecated   HTTP/b.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
```

#### HealthServlet.kt

```
import org.ietf.jgss.GSSCredential
import org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
import org.ietf.jgss.Oid
import java.io.IOException
import java.security.PrivilegedActionException
import java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction
import java.util.Base64
import javax.security.auth.Subject
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException
import javax.servlet.ServletException
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

@WebServlet("/healthz")
class HealthServlet : HttpServlet() {
    @Throws(ServletException::class, IOException::class)
    override fun doGet(req: HttpServletRequest, resp: HttpServletResponse) {
        val authorization = req.getHeader("Authorization") ?: let {
            resp.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Negotiate")
            resp.status = HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED
            return
        }

        val negotiate = authorization.substringAfter(' ')
        val token = Base64.getDecoder().decode(negotiate)

        // Get own Kerberos credentials for accepting connection
        val manager = GSSManager.getInstance()
        val spnegoOid = Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.2")

        var serverCreds: GSSCredential? = null
        this.loginAndAction(PrivilegedExceptionAction {
            serverCreds = manager.createCredential(null, GSSCredential.DEFAULT_LIFETIME, spnegoOid, GSSCredential.ACCEPT_ONLY)
        })

        val context = manager.createContext(serverCreds as GSSCredential)

        val respToken = context!!.acceptSecContext(token, 0, token.size)
        val respNegotiate = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(respToken)

        // Send a token to the peer if one was generated by
        // acceptSecContext
        if (respToken != null) {
            System.err.println("Will send token of size " + token.size + " from acceptSecContext.")

            resp.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Negotiate $respNegotiate")
            resp.status = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK

            resp.writer.println(context.srcName)
        }

        System.err.println("Context Established! ")
        System.err.println("Client principal is " + context.srcName)
        System.err.println("Server principal is " + context.targName)

        /*
         * If mutual authentication did not take place, then
         * only the client was authenticated to the
         * server. Otherwise, both client and server were
         * authenticated to each other.
         */
        if (context.mutualAuthState)
            System.err.println("Mutual authentication took place!")
    }

    @Throws(LoginException::class, PrivilegedActionException::class)
    private fun <T> loginAndAction(action: PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>) {
        val context = LoginContext("example")
        context.login()

        // Perform action as authenticated user
        val subject = context.subject
        println(subject)

        Subject.doAs(subject, action)
        context.logout()
    }
}
```

#### Log

```
Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt false ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is /root/HTTP.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
Looking for keys for: HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Found unsupported keytype (1) for HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Found unsupported keytype (3) for HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Added key: 23version: 2
Added key: 17version: 2
Added key: 18version: 2
Looking for keys for: HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Found unsupported keytype (1) for HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Found unsupported keytype (3) for HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Added key: 23version: 2
Added key: 17version: 2
Added key: 18version: 2
Using builtin default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 18 17 20 19 16 23.
>>> KrbAsReq creating message
getKDCFromDNS using UDP
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=dc1.corp.example.com. UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=175
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=dc1.corp.example.com. UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=175
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=315
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 2
     PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 16

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 15

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 19
     PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 18, salt = CORP.EXAMPLE.COMa, s2kparams = 0000: 00 00 10 00                                        ....

>>> KdcAccessibility: remove dc1.corp.example.com.:88
>>> KDCRep: init() encoding tag is 126 req type is 11
>>>KRBError:
     sTime is Thu May 21 20:14:03 UTC 2020 1590092043000
     suSec is 748632
     error code is 25
     error Message is Additional pre-authentication required
     crealm is CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
     cname is HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
     sname is krbtgt/CORP.EXAMPLE.COM@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
     eData provided.
     msgType is 30
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 2
     PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 16

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 15

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 19
     PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 18, salt = CORP.EXAMPLE.COMa, s2kparams = 0000: 00 00 10 00                                        ....

KRBError received: Need to use PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP/PA-PK-AS-REQ
KrbAsReqBuilder: PREAUTH FAILED/REQ, re-send AS-REQ
Using builtin default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 18 17 20 19 16 23.
Looking for keys for: HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Found unsupported keytype (1) for HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Found unsupported keytype (3) for HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Added key: 23version: 2
Added key: 17version: 2
Added key: 18version: 2
Looking for keys for: HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Found unsupported keytype (1) for HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Found unsupported keytype (3) for HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Added key: 23version: 2
Added key: 17version: 2
Added key: 18version: 2
Using builtin default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 18 17 20 19 16 23.
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> KrbAsReq creating message
getKDCFromDNS using UDP
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=dc1.corp.example.com. UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=264
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=dc1.corp.example.com. UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=264
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=199
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=dc1.corp.example.com. TCP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=264
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=dc1.corp.example.com. TCP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=264
>>>DEBUG: TCPClient reading 1511 bytes
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=1511
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove dc1.corp.example.com.:88
Looking for keys for: HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Found unsupported keytype (1) for HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Found unsupported keytype (3) for HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Added key: 23version: 2
Added key: 17version: 2
Added key: 18version: 2
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> KrbAsRep cons in KrbAsReq.getReply HTTP/a.example.com
principal is HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Will use keytab
Commit Succeeded 

Subject:
    Principal: HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
    Private Credential: Ticket (hex) = 
... REDACTED ...

Client Principal = HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Server Principal = krbtgt/CORP.EXAMPLE.COM@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Session Key = EncryptionKey: keyType=18 keyBytes (hex dump)=
... REDACTED ...


Forwardable Ticket false
Forwarded Ticket false
Proxiable Ticket false
Proxy Ticket false
Postdated Ticket false
Renewable Ticket false
Initial Ticket true
Auth Time = Thu May 21 20:14:03 UTC 2020
Start Time = Thu May 21 20:14:03 UTC 2020
End Time = Fri May 22 06:14:03 UTC 2020
Renew Till = null
Client Addresses  Null 
    Private Credential: /root/HTTP.keytab for HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM

Found KeyTab /root/HTTP.keytab for HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Found KeyTab /root/HTTP.keytab for HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Found ticket for HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM to go to krbtgt/CORP.EXAMPLE.COM@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM expiring on Fri May 22 06:14:03 UTC 2020
        [Krb5LoginModule]: Entering logout
        [Krb5LoginModule]: logged out Subject
Entered SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: receiving token = ... REDACTED ...
SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2
SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.2.752.43.14.3
SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mech Token
SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: received token of type = SPNEGO NegTokenInit
SpNegoContext: negotiated mechanism = 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2
Entered Krb5Context.acceptSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
Looking for keys for: HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Found unsupported keytype (1) for HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Found unsupported keytype (3) for HTTP/a.example.com@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM
Added key: 23version: 2
Added key: 17version: 2
Added key: 18version: 2
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
Servlet.service() for servlet [HealthServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.security.GeneralSecurityException: Checksum failed
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.AesDkCrypto.decryptCTS(AesDkCrypto.java:451)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.AesDkCrypto.decrypt(AesDkCrypto.java:272)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256.decrypt(Aes256.java:76)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.decrypt(Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.java:100)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.decrypt(Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.java:94)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.EncryptedData.decrypt(EncryptedData.java:180)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.authenticate(KrbApReq.java:281)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.<init>(KrbApReq.java:149)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.krb5.InitSecContextToken.<init>(InitSecContextToken.java:139)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:832)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:361)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:303)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.GSS_acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:905)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:556)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:361)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:303)
    at HealthServlet.doGet(HealthServlet.kt:43)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(Nio2Endpoint.java:1676)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.processSocket(AbstractEndpoint.java:1087)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2SocketWrapper$2.completed(Nio2Endpoint.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2SocketWrapper$2.completed(Nio2Endpoint.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:127)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:219)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Original

So far the only solution I've found is to patch Samba, regressing it to the old SPN behavior.

```
diff --git a/source4/heimdal/kdc/kerberos5.c b/source4/heimdal/kdc/kerberos5.c
index 27d38ad84b7..fdf249bc08d 100644
--- a/source4/heimdal/kdc/kerberos5.c
+++ b/source4/heimdal/kdc/kerberos5.c
@@ -762,9 +762,9 @@ kdc_check_flags(krb5_context context,
        return KRB5KDC_ERR_POLICY;
    }

-   if(!client->flags.client){
+   if (!is_as_req && !client->flags.client){
        kdc_log(context, config, 0,
-           "Principal may not act as client -- %s", client_name);
+           "Principal may only act as client in AS-REQ -- %s", client_name);
        return KRB5KDC_ERR_POLICY;
    }

@@ -1056,7 +1056,7 @@ _kdc_as_rep(krb5_context context,
      */

     ret = _kdc_db_fetch(context, config, client_princ,
-           HDB_F_GET_CLIENT | flags, NULL,
+           HDB_F_GET_ANY | flags, NULL,
            &clientdb, &client);
     if(ret == HDB_ERR_NOT_FOUND_HERE) {
    kdc_log(context, config, 5, "client %s does not have secrets at this KDC, need to proxy", client_name);
```

#### Edit 1

As explained in the commit message, the behavior of using SPNs in AS-REQ is incorrect.

https://gitlab.com/samba-team/samba/-/commit/a6182bd9512e6c78cfd2127790419418ab776be9

So the right approach would be to investigate the `Checksum failed` exceptions of Java instead of patching Samba.